# Is there a way to extract "body" from the request function?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to extract "body" from the request function?

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://dev-5j3doydu.au.auth0.com/oauth/token",
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
  body:client_id
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  return body; 
});
```

Comment: Btw: `request` has been deprecated and should not be used in new projects anymore.

Comment: No, there is not.  Use the result inside the callback or call another function and pass the body to it.  This is how asynchronous callbacks work in Javascript.

Comment: This is actually the code from Auth0. And I see, guess I just have to use it in side of the function.